# WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED

Tags: ubuntu

I keep getting the usual 
"WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!

IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY! Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)! It is also possible that a host key has just been changed."
message when trying to connect with ubuntu.

I know what I did to get it but now I can't get it back right.  I was having an issue with the known_hosts file earlier so I deleted it like I have done before and then tried to reconnect so the file would be remade.

Now I am getting that error and I have no known_host file to edit and remove the bad key. I have seen codes about resetting the file and all that but what if the file is not created?

Answer (score 25):

I assume this is a message from your ssh client when trying to connect to a remote host. (You should really post the full error message and give more context.) In either case, to get rid of the error, the best way to delete the offending entry in your known_hosts file is to run:

```
ssh-keygen -R server.example.com
```

Comment: Yes, I can not run that command because the known_host file does not exist and it will not create itself when I try to connect to a host.

Comment: Just `touch .ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: touch .ssh/known_hosts, is that a command line?

Comment: Yes, that is a command line. Also make sure that you don't accidentally have a ~/.ssh/known_hosts2

Comment: The touch .ssh/known_hosts line made a view only known_host file. I still get the same error when I try to connect.
  WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
27:63:47:21:67:96:a0:9d:0d:c6:50:eb:ef:26:64:25.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key

Comment: in /root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R *.*.*.*
RSA host key for *.*.*.* has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.

Comment: There, the error message states exactly what you need: ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R ...
You have a known_hosts-file i /root/.ssh, and are probably running your ssh command using sudo...

Comment: ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R *.*.*.*
/root/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /root/.ssh/known_hosts.old

home/mainuser/.ssh/known_host is empty and "write only" and I don't see a known_hosts.old

It did seem to connect though.

Comment: That is because it is reading /root/.ssh/known_hosts, not /home/mainuser/.ssh/known_hosts. Different users (root vs mainuser), different directories